# iPhone - How to add the page curl effect to the custom views?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, quartz-graphics, page-curl

I have seen a few libraries ( e.g https://github.com/brow/leaves ) on how to implement page curl effect on iOS .

But these are limited to a pdf , image or coregraphics drawing . What I want to implement is a page shoule be replaced by a custom view ( like a view containing a couple of buttons , an imageview , a UITableView etc ) . 
 Now my question is how do we have page curl effects for a set of different custom views ( from different view controllers ) ?

Comment: May be duplicate question for http://stackoverflow.com/a/9443367/846372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve? Is it kind of modal dialog with controls behind a curled-up corner like in maps app or a full book style page curl like in iBooks?

For the first look at Steve Job's answer (never thought I'd say this), the latter can be done with `UIPageViewController` (look [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_a_Page_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_UIPageViewController) to start with UIPageViewController).

Comment: yes exactly , I want the second one . Is there any way I can do it in 4.0 cause UIPageViewController is available only from iOS 5.0 onwards .

Comment: Nope, no way in 4.x using built-in stuff as far as I know (and a searched a lot). In iOS Versions older than 5 there are build-in animations for  curl, but only up and down. However there are some open implementations for iPhone/iPad of book-like curling, but they are buggy, slow, hard to use/understand and/or use private APIs.

Answer (score 2):

```
SampleViewController *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl]; 
[self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `transitionFromView` and `transitionWithView` methods in `UIView`:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
                  duration:0.2
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    [fromView removeFromSuperview]; 
                    [containerView addSubview:toView]; 
                }
                completion:NULL
 ];
```

The `options` parameter can be set to `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp` / `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown`.